# PHP - I want to set a value to false when clicking a type="reset" button. How can I achieve that?

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I have been trying to learn PHP for the past week now.
I have created a form which acts like a calculator in which two values are either added up, subtracted, multiplied or divided.

```
$cal = new calculator();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $result = $cal->getresult($_POST['n1'],$_POST['n2'],$_POST['op']);
}

if(isset($_POST['reset'])){   
$result = false;
}

?>

<form method="post">
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><b><?php echo $result; ?></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zahl 1 </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="n1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Zahl 2 </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="n2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Select Oprator</td>
        <td><select name="op">
            <option value="+">+</option>
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="*">*</option>
            <option value="/">/</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Berechnen"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Beforehand I define the calculator-class but it is not relevant for this question.
So what I want to do is when I click the

```
<td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
```

button i want the variable $result to be defined as empty, which I want to achieve by

```
if(isset($_POST['reset'])){   
$result = false;
}
```

In effect, php should not show the result on top of the document, because

```
<tr>
        <td><b><?php echo $result; ?></b></td>
    </tr>
```

is empty?

Unfortunately, that doesn't happen. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Using reset will only clear the form's input values, not any calculation you have done. You would have to either a.) submit the form and clear the result if the form is empty or 2.) use JavaScript to clear the result.

Comment: Perhaps you can use ajax with a get parameter assigned to a button or a href

Answer (score 0):

The reset button won't submit your form, which is what needs to happen in order for your PHP to run. You *can*, however, use multiple submit buttons in a form and name them differently. Try this:

```
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
```

This will trigger the form to submit, but will come across as "reset" in your POST data, and should subsequently trigger your logic to clear values.

---

**EDIT:**

The `$result` variable is dead once your page is processed server side. By time it shows up in your browser, that part of the request is over and the variable doesn't exist, so clicking a "reset" button doesn't really matter. It sounds like you want to clear the form and also clear the result display. In that case, continue to use the reset button as you were.

And then add some javascript to clear out the result. For that to work, you need to add an ID or class to the element holding it:

```
<tr>
    <td>
       <b id="result">
          <?php echo $result; ?>
       </b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then add a click handler, either in a JS file, in `<script>` tags, or right on the element itself:

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" onClick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='0';">
```

That would set it to "0".

Comment: I see! I don't actually get a value which can be saved as "$_POST['reset']", right? Is there a way to get a value when clicking a reset-button?

Comment: The button you click will be sent in your `$_POST` data. You will _also_ get the form values, in case you want to carry them over to the next request. Try doing a `var_dump($_POST);` and see what you get.

Comment: I mean I want the button to act as a classic reset button AND carry out the "$result = false;" action. Is there a way to achieve that with only one visible button?

Comment: @Denny You could do it in Javascript before the form submits.